# Percent change of values that are not NaN

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 11, 20, 80, 1, 22], 'b':['x', np.nan, 'x', np.nan, np.nan, 'x']})
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
    a    b     c
0  10    x     NaN
1  11  NaN     NaN
2  20    x     100
3  80  NaN     NaN
4   1  NaN     NaN
5  22    x     10
```

I want to create column `c` which is the perecent change of values of column `a` that are not `NaN` in `b`.
For example 100 in `c` is the result of percent change of 20 and 10.

I have tried to create a new dataframe by using `df.loc[df.b.notna(), 'a'].values` but I still cannot get the result that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the `pct_change()` after selecting the rows from `a` corresponds to the not null value from `b`.

```py
df['c'] = df.loc[df['b'].eq('x'), 'a'].pct_change().mul(100)
# or
df['c'] = df.loc[df['b'].notnull(), 'a'].pct_change().mul(100)
```

```
print(df)

    a    b      c
0  10    x    NaN
1  11  NaN    NaN
2  20    x  100.0
3  80  NaN    NaN
4   1  NaN    NaN
5  22    x   10.0
```